# Merge local master branch with remote master branch in Git

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm in a strange situation: I have copied a directory (local repository) from a former developer on to my machine. There have been several commits to the remote master that are NOT in his local repository.

**How do I merge the local copy of master with the most up-to-date changes of the remote master?**

Comment: Is the repo still set up to point at the same remote master? Is there anything that prevents you from simply pulling & merging?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Case 1: remote/master has everything that local master has

If `remote/master` contains all of the commits that the local `master` contains, simply do a `git pull`:

```
git checkout master
git pull remote master
```

You can check if the local `master` has commits that `remote/master` doesn't by using the following:

```
git fetch remote
git log --oneline --graph remote/master..master
```

That will show you all commits that are contained in `master` but not in `remote/master`. If you don't see any output, that means `remote/master` has everything that the local `master` has.

### Case 2: local master has commits that remote/master doesn't have

If the local `master` contains commits that `remote/master` doesn't contain, you'll have to figure out how you want to handle that. Do you want to keep them and merge them with `remote/master`, or do you simply want to throw them away?

#### Case 2a: merge/rebase local master commits into remote/master

If you want to keep them, you can either `merge` or `rebase` the local `master` with `remote/master`:

```bash
git checkout master
git fetch <remote>

# Merge remote/master
git merge remote/master

# Or rebase local commits on top instead
git rebase remote/master

# Push the results
git push remote master
```

#### Case 2b: throw away local master commits

If you don't want to keep the local commits, then just do a hard reset of the local `master` to the same point as the `remote/master`:

```bash
git checkout master
git fetch remote
git reset --hard remote/master
```

### Documentation

You can read more about all of these commands from the [Git documentation](http://jk.gs/git.html). I also highly recommend the excellent [free online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), especially chapters 1-3 and 6-6.5.

Comment: Thanks. What if the remote is a private repo? the "git merge" step is failing because I'm failing to get authenticated into the remote..

Comment: @MishaTeplitskiy `git merge` only operates on local copies of data, it shouldn't fail because of authentication issues with a private remote repo. I think you mean that `git fetch` or `git pull` is failing, would that be correct? Sounds to me like you need to resolve the authentication issue. How are you connecting to the remote, through SSH? Do you have the proper credentials to access the private remote? Are you using GitHub or Bitbucket, or something similar? Or is the remote self-hosted somewhere?

Comment: thanks @Cupcake. I had a permissions issue with ssh and whatnot that I've since fixed. Thanks!